# Why model equation output does not match model trained output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

So I am quiet new to deep learning. So bear with me. I have an ANN and I have a housing prices prediction dataset that I feed to it. I cleaned the dataset, normalized the output (taking log) and split the dataset and trained the model and extracted the weights and bias. I hard coded the my own neural network equation using these weights and biases (which is actually a function) that returns the predicted output. Now I was assuming that if I compare a value from the predicted output by the trained model using `model.predict()` and then use the same inputs and feed it into my equation then both the outputs should match. However this is not the case. And before anyone else asks I am using 3 layered model with (12,8,1) and relu in first 2 layers and linear in the last layer and I also applied my activation function to the output of all the layers(if -ve then return 0 else the value). So, I want to know if there is any other reason why these outputs won't match.
This is what my equation looks like roughly (not reproducible) :

````
layer1:
L1N0=activation_function(I1*w(0,0)+I2*w(0,1)+I3*w(0,2)+b1N0)
L1N1=activation_function(I1*w(0,1)+I2*w(1,1)+I3*w(1,2)+b1N1)
layer2:
L2N0=activation_function(L1N0*w_layer2(0,0)+L1N0*w_layer2(0,1)+b2N0)
```
````

Comment: It will be helpful if your provide your keras code with some example data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi As you mentioned here "if I compare a value from the predicted output by the trained model using model.predict() and then use the same inputs and feed it into my equation then both the outputs should match"

Yes exactly the model should give you approx. same output as that of you equation provided the model should have trained properly.
By training, the ANN is trying to figure out weights and biases related to layers so as to approximate the equation which in this case is the ground truth values.
What your ANN is trying to do is that it trying to approximate the equation as said in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem .

Things you can do to improve accuracy:

- increase epochs
- increase layers
- tryout different learning rates
- tryout different optimizers etc.

Comment: I tried different layers etc but shouldn't the weights and bias that I extract from the training give me exact same answer that the trained model predicted? The output that it is predicting is a log value. My outputs have 1.5 difference between them.

Comment: Did you mean 100% correct prediction ? Just to tell you an AI model in this case ANN approximates the equation so as to get nearly correct prediction. Logically we can have a model with 100% correct prediction but that means the model is over-fitting and thus leading to poor generalization.